# Difference between catch and onErrorResumeNext

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

In RxJS, there seems to be very little difference between an Observable instance's `catch` method and `onErrorResumeNext` method, besides the fact that `onErrorResumeNext` concatenates the original Observable with the Observable parameters whether an error happens or not.

If that's the case, isn't the naming a bit confusing? Because in case there is an error , `onErrorResumeNext` works exactly the same way than `catch` does:

```
var testObservable = Rx.Observable.return(1).concat(Rx.Observable.throw("Error"))

// Both onError and onCatch will emit the same result: 1, 2
var onError = testObservable.onErrorResumeNext(Rx.Observable.return(2));
var onCatch = testObservable.catch(Rx.Observable.return(2));
```

Is there a strong reason for not always using `catch`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are distinct.

As you've noted, both operators handle failure similarly; however, they differ in their handling of completion.

`OnErrorResumeNext` is simply a specialization with the following semantics:

"My query **concatenates** two observables. If the first observable fails, then *resume* with the *next* observable anyway."

`Catch` is far more general:

"My query avoids failure. If the observable fails, then continue with another observable."

If you're avoiding failure on the boundary of concatenation, then use `OnErrorResumeNext`; otherwise, to avoid failures in general use `Catch`.

Comment: The name most likely comes from the Visual Basic `On Error Resume Next` statement, which has semantics similar to this operator.

Comment: @Brandon Also a good point. I decided not to mention it though because I figured if it wasn't an apt name the Rx team wouldn't have used it. And although the OP's question is partially about semantics, I decided to focus my answer on the differences between the operators, which reveals that the name is in fact appropriate.

Comment: Your reply makes sense, thanks. I guess that the confusion is about the naming because, as you point out, the main task of `onErrorResumeNext` is to concatenate, but this is not reflected at all in the name.

Comment: @GiantSquid Well, I think concatenation is implied by the phrase "resume next", but I can see how that could be unclear at first.